# Check all the array has value and not empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

index.html

```
<form id="players_form"  >
    <input type=" text" name="main_name[]" value="1">
    <input type=" text" name="main_name[]" value="2">
    <input type=" text" name="main_name[]" value="3">
    <input type=" text" name="main_name[]" value="4">
    <input type=" text" name="main_name[]" value="5">

    <input type=" text" name="sub_name[]" value="6">
    <input type=" text" name="sub_name[]" value="7">
    <input type=" text" name="sub_name[]" value="8">
    <input type=" text" name="sub_name[]" value="9">
    <input type=" text" name="sub_name[]" value="">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">

 </form>
```

script

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
var data = JSON.stringify($("#players_form").serializeArray());
// alert(data);
$.ajax({ // Send the credential values to another checker.php using Ajax in POST menthod
type: 'POST',
data: {
  list: data
},
url: 'process.php',
success: function(responseText) {
  if (responseText == 1) {
    alert("Sucess");
  }
```

process.php

```
$decoded = json_decode($_REQUEST['list'], true);
print_r(array_filter($decoded));
```

Result

```
Array( [0] => Array ( [name] => main_name[] [value] => 1 )
[1] => Array ( [name] => main_name[] [value] => 2 ) 
[2] => Array ( [name] => main_name[] [value] => 3 ) 
[3] => Array ( [name] => main_name[] [value] => 4 ) 
[4] => Array ( [name] => main_name[] [value] => 5 ) 
[5] => Array ( [name] => sub_name[] [value] => 6 ) 
[6] => Array ( [name] => sub_name[] [value] => 7 ) 
[7] => Array ( [name] => sub_name[] [value] => 8 ) 
[8] => Array ( [name] => sub_name[] [value] => 9 ) 
[9] => Array ( [name] => sub_name[] [value] => ))
```

Expected code

```
if(all the arrays has value)
{
 // True
}
else
{
 Any one of the values in array is empty 
 }
```

Hi friends in the above code I'm sending the form values to process.php through `AJAX function` , in `process.PHP` I should check wheather all the text box should contain values then it should proceed to next step else , it should echo sorry you have empty values . In my code I have last box value as empty `<input type=" text" name="sub_name[]" value="">` in result also it `returns [9] => Array ( [name] => sub_name[] **[value] =>** ))` , How to check whether all the array has value or not . Thanks in advance

Comment: add `required` attribute on all the textboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to validate data before sending it to server. For example:

```
var dataValid = true;
$("#players_form input").each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == ''){
        dataValid = false;
    }
});

if (dataValid){
   // send data
} else {
   alert('Fill in all the data!');
}
```

Then on server, same thing:

```
$valid = true;
foreach($decoded as $input){
    if ($input['value'] == ''){
        $valid = false;
    }
}

if ($valid){
    // done good
} else {
    echo "Fill in all the data!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to check before POSTing the data, [`[].every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) can do that. `every` allows you to check if all elements of an array pass a certain test.

```
var ok = data.every(function(element) {
    return element.value; // if value is empty, it's false
});

if (ok) {
    // POST request
} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way use `empty()` function

```
if(!empty($decoded))
{
 // True
}
else
{
 Any one of the values in array is empty 
 }
```

Comment: I think the best way is to not send the ajax if there are empty input so do the validation in the js part. As commented by Tushar

Answer (score 0):

In PHP5 (>=5.5.0) you can do search through a multi dimensional array

```
$user=Array
(
(0) => Array
    (
        (name) => 'Susan',
        (age) => 21
    ),

(1) => Array
    (
        (name) => 'Mark',
        (age) => 33
    ),

(2) => Array
    (
        (name) => 'Michael',
        (age) => 25
    ));
$key = array_search(21, array_column($user, 'age'));
```

You can search `''` value in your array.